# Does PyString_AS_STRING work different in Windows 64 bits vs 32 bits?

Tags: python, string, embedding

I have the following function:

```
void py_get_var( const char** var_name, int* found, char** resultado )
{
    *found = 0;

    PyObject * module     = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
    PyObject * dictionary = PyModule_GetDict(module);
    PyObject * result     = PyDict_GetItemString(dictionary, *var_name );

    if( result == NULL ){
        *found = 1;
        *resultado = "";
        return;
    }

    #ifdef PY3K
    *resultado = PyBytes_AS_STRING( PyUnicode_AsUTF8String(result) );
    #else
    *resultado = PyString_AS_STRING(result);
    #endif
}
```

which attempts to retrieve a string (it is always a string) from an embedded Python session. It works as intended on Linux, Mac, and Win32 platforms (and several versions of Python).

However, it returns an empty string on Win64. I'm using the GCC compiler on Windows.

Any idea of what can be the reason?

Comment: First, what version of Python? And 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Also, is the module variable a `unicode` or a `str` (assuming you're asking about 2.x)?

Comment: The code is intended to be portable (Linux, OS X and Win) and work with Python 2.x and 3.x. It does work on different Linux flavours and on Win 32 bits. It is now that I test it in Win 64 platform (with 64 bit Python) that it returns empty strings. Incidentally, the strings that it should return were created using json.dumps.

Comment: First, for the case that doesn't work, which version of Python is that? Have you tried it on both 2.7 and 3.4 and they both give you empty strings on 64-bit Windows? If not, which one did you try it on? Second, you still haven't answered whether the variable that you're looking up is a `unicode` or a `bytes` or a whichever-one-is-`str`-in-each-version.

Comment: Funny... The previous code worked in some Windows machines. Failed in others (architecture?). I changed `*resultado = PyString_AS_STRING(result);` to `*resultado = PyString_AsString(result);` and worked... mystery?